# How can I link css/js from main bootstrap theme to subtheme?

Tags: theming

I'm kinda a newbie to web development and web coding languages. I recently installed Drupal 7.54 on localhost (xampp), then loaded it with Bootstrap 3.13 theme but when I come to creating a subtheme, It does not resemble the main theme though I've followed instructions here: https://www.gaslampmedia.com/tutorial-drupal-bootstrap-3-4-subtheme-with-less/

My subtheme looks like this:
[image: Bootstrap subtheme screenshot]

Can anyone configure this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you've got the Drupal Bootstrap site logo means the theme was correctly enabled. However, this is a symptom of the browser not finding your CSS file.

And you don't actually use the Bootstrap CSS that comes with the parent theme. You actually have to import Bootstrap into your SASS/LESS. That's why you need to download Bootstrap to your subtheme (Step 4).

If you're using the SASS/LESS starterkit, you will actually need to compile your CSS (that's steps 4 and 5 of the Overview). Once you've got it compiling, you need to tell your subtheme the path of the compiled CSS by adding it to the info file (step 3 of the Overview).

```
stylesheets[all][] = path/to/compiled/styles.css
```

Comment: I seem to have done what you've stated. Yes, I have downloaded bootstrap source files and added them to my >themes/subtheme folder, which was a less folder from starterkit. I've also used auto-compiler in atom code editor to compile the less file to css, i have also triggered the compiling of style.less from variable-overrides.less file

Comment: the path of the compiled css file is there and correct by default. I have also Disabled the CDN provider so compiled source files can be used, by removing the semi-colon in the subtheme.info file. Here are the links to the screenshots how files look like now @JoseftheDreamer:        [   https://ibb.co/k55vca ]
[ https://ibb.co/kC2aca ]
[ https://ibb.co/gzwOVv  ]